# AJAX search - no results returns last line

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, jquery

I am trying to implement a search box that will search a particular play (AJAX file) for any instances of the word, if the word is found it then outputs that line. My problem is that if no results are found of the word instead of continuing to show the entire play it outputs the last line of the play only.

My function:

```
function searchResults(query) {        
  var temp = "\\b" + query + "\\b";         
  var regex_query = new RegExp(temp, "gi"); 
  var currentLine;
  var num_matching_lines = 0;
  $("#mainOutput").empty();
  $("LINE", current_play_dom).each(function () {
    var line = this;
    currentLine = $(this).text();           
    matchesLine = currentLine.replace(regex_query, '<span class="query_match">' + query + '</span>');
    if ( currentLine.search(regex_query) > 0 ) {
      num_matching_lines++ 
      $("#mainOutput").append("<br /><p class='speaker_match'>"+  $(line).parent().find('SPEAKER').text() +"</p>");
      $("#mainOutput").append("<p class='act_match'>"+  $(line).parent().parent().parent().children(':first-child').text()+"</p>");
      $("#mainOutput").append("<p class='scene_match'>"+  $(line).parent().parent().children(':first-child').text() +"</p>");
      $("#mainOutput").append("<p>" + matchesLine + "</p>");
      $("#mainOutput").append("<br>");
    }   
  });
  $("#mainOutput").append("<p>" + matchesLine + "</p>");
  $("#sideInfo").append("<p>Found " + query + " in " + num_matching_lines + " lines</p>");
}
```

Also as a side question is there a neater way to do this:
`$(line).parent().parent().parent().children(':first-child')`

Comment: Why don't you do the searching serverside and just have the JS format the output?

Comment: It's an academic exercise so we are restricted in how we can do it.